# MinGW stack size reserved or committed?

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64

MSVC has the linker option "/STACK:reserve[,commit]".

Allowing you to specify both how much is reserved and committed.

MinGW has the option "--stack < size >".

It only takes a single parameter.

Is this "size" reserved or committed?

I'm trying to pre-commit the whole stack, so stack probing is not required at runtime; and I can't find any documentation on this switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Xlinker --stack=0x100000,0x100000

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options

Comment: It sounds like a good answer, unfortunately, for some unknown reason, this did not work for us - see https://github.com/OpenSmalltalk/opensmalltalk-vm/commit/f679770b318090f0abdddeabc59568a6520ed7f2

Comment: Ah, there is no = after the --stack, so it should be `-Xlinker --stack -Xlinker 0x100000,0x100000`. This still did not work for me though...